# Problem with importing twill3 in Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, twill

I'm trying to write a little web scraping script, and I'm trying to use twill3, but it keeps giving me the error

File "mypath\twill3\other_packages\subprocess.py", line 392

False = 0

SyntaxError: cannot assign to False

I really have no idea what to do with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show some code.

Comment: And False is a Keyword you cant assign anything to it because it has some predefined functionality.  keyword detail https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_keywords.asp